# I have set the TEMPLATES DIRS, but there still have the error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

The error in my server terminal:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/luowensheng/Desktop/testpython/mysite/mysite/settings.py", line 57, in <module>
    'DIRS': [os.path.join()],
TypeError: join() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

But in my PyCharm I set the `TEMPLATES`'s `DIRS` in settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],    # this is the 57tr line
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: do print TEMPLATES  we can identify where is the error occurs

Comment: If you have a look at the error, the line states: `'DIRS': [os.path.join()],`, so there is a difference between the code you are seeing in the editor ( `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`), and what is ultimately run (`'DIRS': [os.path.join()],`)

Comment: Try clearing settings.pyc file

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed How to print it?

Comment: add this below TEMPLATES  (line ~70) `print(TEMPLATES)`

Comment: error sorted .. there is compiler mismatch .. your code was correct but your compiled file have bug which is complied before itself. @VikashSingh gave you a correct solution ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to try:

- Make sure code changes visible in the editor are saved in .py file.
  (you can open the py file in another editor vi/vim to verify this)
- Remove settings.pyc file and retry.
  `find . -name '*.pyc' -delete` command to remove *.pyc file from project.

Comment: I delete the settings.pyc and re-runserver it works.

Comment: awesome :) Glad I could help

Comment: deleting pyc will solve most of the cache issue which is arise when code was code still getting error... it is due compiled mismatch  right?

Comment: @Mohideen exactly.

Comment: upvote for present of mind solution .. even i got similar error it will help  me to solve.. thanks ..